# How I can see the actual bit sequence of 0.1 in Python?

Tags: python, binary

## Question

How can I visualize the floating number `0.1` in the 64 bit binary format stored in memory in Python, like in the image? A Python code which can show the sign bit, exponent bits, and precision bits like (1,01010110111,1010101...).

- [Why is 0.1 + 0.2 Not Equal to 0.3 in Most Programming Languages?](https://medium.com/better-programming/why-is-0-1-0-2-not-equal-to-0-3-in-most-programming-languages-99432310d476)

[image]

## Background

A float number needs to be represented in binary bits, and as far as I could understand from the articles, it is  `± p × 2**e` where ± is i 1 bit, p is 52 bits precision, and e is exponent in 11 bits.

- [Anatomy of a floating point number](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/04/06/anatomy-of-a-floating-point-number/)
- [Why can't decimal numbers be represented exactly in binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary)

I suppose the reason for `(3 * 0.1 == 0.3) is False` is because `0.1` cannot be represented in 64 bits and it is `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625` in Python in decimal.

```
print(3 * 0.1 == 0.3)     # False
print(0.3 * 1 == 0.3)     # True

print("%0.55f" % (1.0 / 10))
-----
0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625

print("%0.55f" % (0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625 - 0.1))
-----
0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

However, still not able to understand how it works and would like to see how it looks like in the binary format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `struct` module to pack the floating-point value into a buffer.  The `"d"` [format string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters) gives an 8-byte `double`.

```
import struct

x = float(0.1)
buf = struct.pack("d", x)
print(buf)  # b'\x9a\x99\x99\x99\x99\x99\xb9?'

# Hex dump, for readability
print(" ".join("{:02X}".format(b) for b in buf))  # 9A 99 99 99 99 99 B9 3F
```

The buffer will reflect the native endianness of your system.  You can also experiment with [byte-order specifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) in the format string.

You can also re-interpret the same bytes as an integer.  To do this, you can use the unsigned integer type of the same size (8 bytes).  In this case, it would be the `long long` unsigned integer (format string `"Q"`):

```
# Interpret bytes as unsigned integer.
i, = struct.unpack("Q", buf)
print("{:0>16X}".format(i))  # 3FB999999999999A
```

Finally, if you want, you can interpret the buffer as a `double`, and confirm that the value survives a round-trip serialization:

```
x2, = struct.unpack("d", buf)
print(x2)       # 0.1
print(x2 == x)  # True
```

### Viewing floating-point representation components

To view the individual components of the floating point number, you can examine parts of the integer equivalent using bitmasks.

```
import struct

x = -(16 + 4 + 2 + 1 + 0.5)
buf = struct.pack("d", x)
i, = struct.unpack("Q", buf)
```

Here, `x` has a value of `-0b10111.1`, or equivalently `-0b1.01111 * 2^4`.

There are two important notes about the [IEEE 753 representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754):

- the exponent has a *bias* of 1023, so we expect a value of 1027 stored in the exponent.
- the mantissa’s leading `1` is implicit, so we expect the mantissa bits to be `01111`.

We can use the appropriate masks for the bit patterns shown in the question, then print in binary

```
print(format(i, '0>64b'))

SIGN_MASK = 0x8000000000000000
EXPN_MASK = 0x7FF0000000000000
MANT_MASK = 0x000FFFFFFFFFFFFF
print(format(i & SIGN_MASK, '0>1b')[:1])
print(format(i & EXPN_MASK, '0>11b')[:11])
print(format(i & MANT_MASK, '0>52b'))
```

Results:

```
1100000000110111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1
10000000011
0111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer on the module. Could you also help to know how I can see the exponent, precision parts using the module?

Comment: Done: you can apply bit masks to the integer equivalent to the bit pattern.